# how to block inappropriate ads from admob account

Tags: android, admob

I am making some religious android apps, and I am also using ad-mob ads in my apps. Some of ads are inappropriate like **Leo privacy guard** as they have **sexual graphics** in ads.I don't want to display this ads in my apps. How do i block this specific ads.
In ad-mob account there are **"allow & block ads"** option, but how do i find this specific ads to block.
Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because advertising.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you cannot block individual ads if you do not have the Advertiser URL, but you can block groups that are known to be sensitive.

some categories that i disabled are  under "Allow & Block Ads">"Sensitive Categories" >

- get Rich Quick
- Sexual & Reproductive Health
- Dating

I also disabled the "YOU MAY HAVE A VIRUS" ads.
You can find these ads under

"General Categories"> "Computers & Consumer Electronics">"Computers"> "Software"> "Internet Software & Web Goodies"

Comment: Thanks.
Can we find specific ads? for example I want to find "Leo Privacy Guard" ads.
and please explain "advertiser URL". is it the URL of android app on google play store?

Comment: this might help https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150172?hl=en.

Comment: Worked Perfect for me. Just block sexual categories and your given three categories.

Comment: This article might help https://medium.com/@codewithuse/how-to-block-illuminati-ads-in-an-admob-account-942dc1ef5870